# Node.js fails to start with v8 symbol error

Tags: node.js, centos, v8

I installed the nodejs package on CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

But it crashed on startup when run with no arguments:

```
[root@lcnolw1073 ~]# nodejs

    nodejs: ../src/handle_wrap.cc:65: static v8::Handle<v8::Value> node::HandleWrap::Unref(const v8::Arguments&): Assertion `args.Holder()->InternalFieldCount() > 0' failed.
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

And also with an empty file:

```
[root@lcnolw1073 ~]# nodejs /dev/null
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```